# Automatically resize my DataGrid column widths when the language changes

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an DataGrid in WPF that contains multilingual column headers. The columns automatically size to the correct width when the DataGrid is initially created. When the user changes the language, the column headers no longer fit. I would like them to resize again. I have tried UpdateLayout and InvalidateParentLayout on my DataGrid. Neither worked.

```
                <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderIDTemplate">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Library_UC, Path=DataContext.Language_Library.ID}"/>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderIDTemplate}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource IDTemplate}" Width="Auto"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably when you change the language a request is being sent to the server, so you have an event handler that's being triggered by your language change. Likely your data is also being refreshed. So, let's loop your columns and set their size:

```
foreach (DataGridColumn c in yourGrid.Columns) {
    column.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
}
```

[DataGridView.AutoResizeColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autoresizecolumn?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) might also help.